# Invalid template library specified

Tags: django

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.core.mail import send_mass_mail
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

import json
import datetime

from models import Competence, Question, Answer, Profession, PROFESSION_CHOICES,\
                   Service, CustomUser, Tag


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'competentions_app/index.html', {})
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/competences/competentions_app/views.py", line 21, in index
    return render(request, 'competentions_app/index.html', {})
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 67, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 18, in get_template
    engines = _engine_list(using)
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 72, in _engine_list
    return engines.all() if using is None else [engines[using]]
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 89, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 80, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 30, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 48, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 113, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/var/www/sampleapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 130, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'competentions_app.templatetags.backend_utils': No module named social.backends.oauth
```

Comment: What's in settings `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`?

Comment: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

Comment: So you don't have `social.backends.oauth` there?

Comment: I added. Nothing changed.

Comment: show how you are trying to load the tag library and also show the installed apps section of your settings